# jquery Live update after a Live call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Having some serious troubles with making a Live update after a Live call. The event is added to the dBase, but I don't seem to get to change the contents of the  changed.
As you can see, we have a unique div id in which we want the confirmation to show (being: '#yvr_add'+id).

Just to be clear: this takes place within a

"live('click',function()"

. Tried everything so far (even live reloading divs), but I just don't get it running.

Yes sir (@Ohgodwhy),

This is the code, passing two vars: a YouTube videoId and a personal videobookID on our server.

```
$('.yt_add_vid').live('click',function(){
    var addItem = $(this).attr('id');
    var selectVal = $('#album'+addItem + ' :selected').val();
    var dataString = 'ytid='+ addItem + '&bookid=' + selectVal;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/xxx/do_my_update.php",
            cache: false,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data){
                $('#yvr_add'+ytid).html('added your entry.'); 
            },
            error : function(data) { 
                alert('Dude, stay focussed now!');
            } 
        });
});
```

Comment: FYI .live() is deprecated in favor of .on()

Comment: @Nathan Bouscal FYI in 1.9+ `.live()` is removed instead of deprecated.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I stand corrected, I hadn't noticed that and the docs don't seem to mention it. Thanks!

Comment: I know...that will be our first update after getting this running! :-)

Comment: So first get it working, then fix it! Seems like a good idea?

Comment: Could you please show the entire click function? You're saying the database updates based on the event, so you know the ajax call is hitting the server. Can we see how you generate the variable `id`, and how the div is structured that we're trying to target? (html)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I updated the code with the entire click function.

Comment: I still don't see you declaring `ytid` anywhere, copy-pasta problems, or is that just declared someone else globally?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with the return of

```
success: function(data){...
```

you can do anything after that.

Thanks for the respones guys!